# Nginx remove everything after subdirectory

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

Tried searching on the forums for an answer but I'm quite stuck...

I have a page called course which used to have a load of sub pages but now I need all requests for those subpages to redirect back to the course page. 
E.g.

```
http://www.example.com/course/whatever   
http://www.example.com/course/WHATEVER
http://www.example.com/course/123456whatever
http://www.example.com/course/whatever/whatever
```

Redirect to:

```
http://www.example.com/course/
```

I've tried this and it gives me an infinite loop:

```
rewrite (?i)^(/course/)(.*) http://www.example.com/course permanent;
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite ^/course/. /course/ permanent;
```

Regexp `^/course/.` will match everything that starts with `/course/` except `/course/` itself and redirect it to `/course/`.

Comment: Thank you very much Alexey this worked perfectly! Was your answer informed by knowing regex or through your experience with nginx?

Comment: Both. I work with nginx since at least v0.8 and know regexp's pretty well

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
rewrite ^/course/(.*)$ /course/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Adding a bit of explanation would add to this answer.

Comment: Remove $1 and replace * with +